# NET::SFTP:Foreign Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: perl

When perl script initiate a sftp connection via `NET::SFTP:Foreign` module to the remote server it fails with the below error log message.  I tried `sftp` unix command from command prompt  to the same remote server it logs in successfully.  Not sure why perl code is failing. OS Solaris5.10 i86 architecture.

```
Permission denied (gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive).
unable to connect to remote host iblpdb.it.com.au: SSH slave exited unexpectedly with error code 255
```

If fails at the below line of code

```
my  $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new("$sftpServer",
                                     user=>$sftpUsername,
                                     password=>$sftpPassword,
                                     asks_for_username_at_login=>1,
                                     port=>'22');
 $sftp->die_on_error("unable to connect to remote host $sftpServer");
```

If SFTP unix manual command is working with the same login and paasword  then  the perl script also should work.  Not sure what this error denotes.

Comment: Why are you using setting the `asks_for_username_at_login`? It is very rarely needed.

Comment: Have a valid setting for  asks_for_username_at_login It should work

Comment: Enable debugging on the module (`$Net::SFTP::Foreign::debug=-1`) and on ssh (passing the options `more => '-vvv'` into the constructor ) and post the full log.

Comment: sure will do that.  Thanks a lot for the info.